# How to register UDF with no argument in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, lambda, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have tried Spark UDF with parameter using lambda function and register it. but how could I create udf with not argument  and registrar it I have tried this my sample code will expected to show current time

from datetime import datetime
   from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

```
def getTime():
    timevalue=datetime.now()
    return timevalue 

udfGateTime=udf(getTime,TimestampType())
```

But PySpark is showing

```
NameError: name 'TimestampType' is not defined
```

which probably means my UDF is not registered
I was comfortable with this format

```py
spark.udf.register('GATE_TIME', lambda():getTime(), TimestampType())
```

but does lambda function take empty argument? Though I didn't try it, I am a bit confused. How could I write the code for registering this getTime() function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `lambda` expression can be nullary. You're just using incorrect syntax:

  ```py
  spark.udf.register('GATE_TIME', lambda: getTime(), TimestampType())
  ```
- There is nothing special in `lambda` expressions in context of Spark. You can use `getTime` directly:

  ```py
  spark.udf.register('GetTime', getTime, TimestampType())
  ```
- There is no need for inefficient `udf` at all. Spark provides required function out-of-the-box:

  ```py
  spark.sql("SELECT current_timestamp()")
  ```

  or

  ```py
  from pyspark.sql.functions import current_timestamp

  spark.range(0, 2).select(current_timestamp())
  ```

Answer (score 3):

I have  done a bit tweak here and it is working well for now

```
import datetime
from pyspark.sql.types import*

def getTime():
    timevalue=datetime.datetime.now()
    return timevalue
def GetVal(x):
    if(True):
     timevalue=getTime()
     return timevalue
spark.udf.register('GetTime', lambda(x):GetVal(x),TimestampType()) 
spark.sql("select GetTime('currenttime')as value ").show()
```

instead of currenttime any value can pass at it will give current date time here

Answer (score 2):

The error "`NameError: name 'TimestampType' is not defined`" seems to be due to the lack of:

```
import pyspark.sql.types.TimestampType
```

For more info regarding `TimeStampType` see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30992905/5088142