# Pyspark udf fails for a function with no arguments but works for a lambda with no arguments

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to add a column to my Spark DataFrame using `withColumn` and udf that takes no arguments. This only seems to work if I use a lambda to encapsulate my original function.

Here's a MWE:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row, SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame([Row(number=i) for i in range(10)])

def foo():
    return 'bar'

udfoo = udf(foo())
df = df.withColumn('word', udfoo())
# Fails with TypeError: _create_udf() missing 1 required positional argument: 'f'

udfoo = udf(lambda: foo())
df = df.withColumn('word', udfoo())
# Works
```

I've managed to achieve the behaviour I want, so a "solution" is not exactly what I'm looking for (even though I welcome any suggestions for a better/more idiomatic way to implement this kind of thing). If anyone lands here looking for a "how to do it" answer, [this other question might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328702/how-to-register-udf-with-no-argument-in-pyspark).

What I'm really after in is an explanation: *why should the first solution fail and the first work?*

I'm using spark 2.4.0 and python 3.7.3 on Ubuntu 18.04.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`udf` expects a function to be passed to it, but when you call `foo()` it evaluates immediately to a string.

You'll see the behavior you're expecting if you use `udf(foo)` instead of `udf(foo())`.

i.e.

```
udfoo = udf(foo)
df = df.withColumn('word', udfoo())
```

In case it helps, if you *are* trying to get a column that is just a constant value, you can use `pyspark.sql.functions.lit`, like:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn('word', F.lit('bar'))
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense, the question had been gnawing at me! And thanks for the explanation about `lit`, this MWE is not exactly what I'm trying to do, but it may help future readers.